# How to reduce AdMob Air Native Extension file size (.ane)?

Tags: android, air, admob

I have managed to include an AdMob banner to my Android AIR mobile application through an android native extension (.ane) which i coded myself.

Problem is, my .ane file size is 5.19 MB.

Which is too big, considering my app is ~700 kb and i also have to embed an AIR captive runtime (>8 MB).

Inside the .ane there is android-support-v4.jar (1.10MB), google-play-services.jar (4.38 MB), google-play-services-res folder (1.19 MB).

Those 3 occupy the most space in my .ane file.

I was wondering is there a way to reduce .ane file size?

Maybe i could delete some classes from inside google-play-services.jar and some values from google-play-serivices-res folder? (Since i only use AdMob and no other services). If so, which ones? How can i know what classes or resources is AdMob using?

And also - can i just open google-play-services.jar with, say 7-Zip, and delete everything i don't need? Wouldn't that be a violation of google services rules or something?

Or perhaps there is a completely different approach, like maybe somehow i don't need to pack google-play-services.jar to my .ane at all, since every Android phone should have those installed already? (Though i tried not to pack it and the AdMob banner did not appear).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GooglePlayServices-7.3.0 ships in chunks, so you could just include the Admob part of GPS. Have a look at the maven repository inside your AndroidSDK.